# How to join two tables based on non-unique id in the first table (SQLite 3.12.2)

Tags: sql, sqlite

Table A's Serial ID is random generated.
Then Table B will according to Table A's serial id and category to generate its sound.

I tried this command, but failed.

```
SELECT          A.timestamp, B.timestamp, B.SerialID, A.Category, B.Sound
FROM            A 
JOIN            B
ON              B.timestamp > A.timestamp
AND             A.SerialID = B.SerialID
ORDER BY        B.timestamp
```

Table A

| Timestamp | SerialID | Category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | Cat |
| 2 | 5 | Dog |
| 10 | 44 | Cat |
| 13 | 5 | Cat |
| 15 | 3 | Dog |

Table B

| Timestamp | SerialID | Sound |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 3 | Meow |
| 4 | 5 | Bark |
| 11 | 44 | Meow |
| 14 | 5 | Meow |
| 16 | 3 | Bark |

Desire table: Table B's first serial id that matched Table A and B.Timestamp greater than A.Timestamp

| A.Timestamp | B.Timestamp | Serial ID | Category | Sound |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 3 | Cat | Meow |
| 2 | 4 | 5 | Dog | Bark |
| 10 | 11 | 44 | Cat | Meow |
| 13 | 14 | 5 | Cat | Meow |
| 15 | 16 | 3 | Dog | Bark |

Comment: What is your MySQL version? The simplest solution may be a lateral join with a limit clause. Lateral joins have been featured since MySQL 8.0.14.

Comment: Sorry for adding wrong information, it is SQLite 3.12.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
   t1.Timestamp AS TimestampA,
   t2.Timestamp AS TimestampB,
   t1.SerialID,
   t1.Category,
   t2.Sound
FROM t1
JOIN t2 ON t1.SerialID = t2.SerialID AND t2.Timestamp = (
  SELECT MIN(t2.Timestamp)
  FROM t2 
  WHERE t2.SerialID = t1.SerialID AND t2.Timestamp >= t1.Timestamp
)
```

Or the same using the `LEAD` window function

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *,
    LEAD(Timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY SerialID ORDER BY Timestamp) as next_timestamp
  FROM t1
)
SELECT
   t1.Timestamp AS TimestampA,
   t2.Timestamp AS TimestampB,
   t1.SerialID,
   t1.Category,
   t2.Sound
FROM cte t1
JOIN t2 ON t1.SerialID = t2.SerialID 
       AND t2.Timestamp >= t1.Timestamp 
       AND (t2.Timestamp < t1.next_timestamp OR next_timestamp IS NULL)
ORDER BY t1.Timestamp
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=cfca7404911972b0063f95522517520e)

Comment: I like both approaches. To put the condition in the `ON` clause is really straight-forward, and the idea with `LEAD` to make this a timestamp range for which we are looking for a match is great thinking.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite solution for this would be a lateral join just picking the desired B row for each A row. But lateral joins are not yet featured in SQLite.

You can get the desired B row with two steps though, by selecting the tmestamp in a subquery in the select clause:

```
select
  ab.timestamp as a_timestamp, b.timestamp as b_timestamp,
  b.serialid, ab.category, b.sound
from
(
  select a.*,
    (
      select b.timestamp
      from b
      where b.serialid = a.serialid
      and b.timestamp > a.timestamp
      order by b.timestamp
      limit 1
    ) as best_timestamp
  from a
) ab
join b on b.serialid = ab.serialid
      and b.timestamp = ab.best_timestamp
order by ab.timestamp, ab.serialid;
```

Another approach uses a window function. There you'd join all candidates and then keep the best one. This is your query with the added picking.

```
select a_timestamp, b_timestamp, serialid, category, sound
from
(
  select 
    a.timestamp as a_timestamp, b.timestamp as b_timestamp,
    b.serialid, a.category, b.sound,
    min(b.timestamp) over (partition by a.serialid) as best_timestamp
  from a
  join b on b.serialid = a.serialid and b.timestamp > a.timestamp
) ab
where b_timestamp = best_timestamp
order by a_timestamp, ab.serialid;
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a join and aggregation and no subqueries:

```
SELECT a.Timestamp a_Timestamp,
       MIN(b.Timestamp) b_Timestamp,
       a.SerialID,
       a.Category,
       b.Sound
FROM TableA a INNER JOIN TableB b
ON b.SerialID = a.SerialID AND b.Timestamp > a.Timestamp
GROUP BY a.Timestamp, a.SerialID;
```

This code relies on SQLite's feature to return the row that contains the minimum value of a column when `MIN()` aggregate function is used.

If the combination of `Timestamp` and `SerialID` is not unique in `TableA` then change to:

```
GROUP BY a.Timestamp, a.SerialID, a.Category
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=c2ea1ed76e4540239188074567f98c9c).

Comment: I like this answer, it is much faster!